# Exercise of position measurements and their values

Tags: statistics

I have this exercise of statistics:

> The attached table shows the approximate values of the distribution in
>   quintiles of the family income per capita in Chile. Which of the
>   following statements is true?
>
> A) 20% have an income equal to 71 thousand pesos.
>
> B) 40% have an income equal to 118 thousand.
>
> C) 60% have an income higher than 182 thousand pesos.
>
> D) 20% have an income not higher than 71 thousand pesos.
>
> E) 20% have an income greater than 333 thousand pesos.

[image]

My development was:

The option $A)$ can't be because the data of the first quintile will be MINOR or EQUAL to quintile 1, i.e. I can not assure you, that all the values under quintile 1 will be equal to 71,000

The option $B)$ Same argument of $A)$

The option $C)$ is false because the $60%$ minimum is $118.000$. So, for this answer to be correct, it should be: *Greater than or equal to 118,000*

The option $D)$ This must be true, because the values under the first quintile are LESS or EQUAL to the first quintile ( $71000$ )

The option $E)$ Also is false, because between the four quintile that is $80$% and $100$% the values will be GREATER or EQUAL to the fourth quintile. i.e. I can not say that they will be greater.

However, the correct answer should be $ E) $ and I do not understand why, so I am thinking that all my procedure is wrong. Thanks in advance

**PS**: I have learned that the values below any quintile ($Q_1$ or $Q_2$  $Q_3$ or $Q_4$) will be LESS or EQUAL.

For example in the statistical sample: `1-1-1-1-5-7-8-9-10`

The $Q_1$ is $1$, and its position is $2.4$, and also below it there are only numbers equal to it (which are the $1$ repeated)

And also ABOVE any quintile ($Q_1$ or $Q_2$, $Q_3$ or Q_4$) will be GREATER or EQUAL

For example, in the sample: `1-3-4-5-6-7-7-7-7-7-7-7`

The $Q_4$ is $7$, and its position is $10.4$, however on it there are values EQUAL to it.

Comment: Are you sure you've presented the question correctly? I agree with your conclusion that $D$ is the answer. Perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

For a sample like this with a large number of possible values we don't worry about how many people have the exact income of the quintile.  We can then say that $20\%$ have an income greater than $333.000$ so E is correct.  Similarly, $20\%$ have an income less than $71.000$ so D is correct as well.  Your point about A and B is correct, you don't have many people with any exact income.  C is not correct because $60\%$ have an income below $182.000$ and $40\%$ have an income above.

There are a number of definitions of exactly how to choose the number you report for a quintile when there are ties and when the number of values is not a multiple of $5$.  These should not matter for a problem like this.

Comment: How you know if all people in the $20$% have less $71000$? instead of exactly $71000$ ?

Comment: D actually accepts those with exactly $71000$ as well as less.  As I was saying, I think here we ignore the fact that people might have exactly the breakpoints and take it to be $20\%$ below the first quintile and so on.  The point of the question seems to me to ask whether you know what a quintile is supposed to be, not the exact details of the definition.  I could be wrong there.

Comment: According to what I know. A quintile divides all data into 20%. Below the first quintile is all 20% of the sample, below the second quintile is all 40% of the sample, below the third is 60%, and below the fourth quintile is all 80% of the sample.

Comment: So, what is wrong?

Comment: Do you disagree with me or not understand what I am saying?  I think I have been clear what I think the answer is, D and E are correct, and why.  I think the issue of people with exactly the breakpoint income is not important.  I can see the other point of view, that whether it is less than or less than or equal is different, but comes down to careful definition of the quintile.  If the problem is referring to that, you need to check that your definition of quintile is the same as the book's.

Comment: My reference book, it only says less or greather. However, the correct alternative should be only E), then there is something that does not fit.